# How to handle urls that need to change between the local and remote repo in github

Tags: git

When I am working on a web development project with a copy of a repository on the server as well as one on my computer, how do I handle cases in which urls need to change in order to run the application in my local repsitory?

For example hostnames that have to change to "localhost".

Do I have to change those urls upon forking and cloning the repository (so I can test and run the app locally) and then before I push it back to the remote repo, rechange them?

Comment: One way would be to rely on `process.env.API_ROOT_URL` in your code. Please provide more infos about your build environment (or lack of) for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix is to make git skip the check for changes using

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

If you want to undo that in the future, execute

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>
```